# JAXB and abstract classes

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, jaxb

I'm trying to use JAXB to unmarshall some XML, but I'm getting an "Unable to create an instance of..." exception.  I understand why--it's trying to make an instance of an abstract class.  What I want is to have it make an instance of a specific implementing class.  My goal with this is to have class-specific checks on setter methods.  Maybe "qux" is a valid baz value for BarImpl, but BarImpl2 wants to do something else.

I got part of the way there by not annotating Foo, but if I unannotate bar, things get ugly.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.junit.Test;


public class JAXBTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws javax.xml.bind.JAXBException {
        String xml = 
            "<foo>" +
            "  <bar>" +
            "    <baz>qux</baz>" +
            "  </bar>" +
            "</foo>";

        javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext context = javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(
                FooImpl.class,
                BarImpl.class
        );

        javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

        unmarshaller.unmarshal(new java.io.StringReader(xml));
    }

    @XmlRootElement(name="foo")
    public static abstract class Foo {
        @XmlElement(name="bar")
        Bar bar;
    }

    @XmlRootElement(name="bar")
    public static abstract class Bar {
        @XmlElement(name="baz")
        String baz;
    }

    public static class FooImpl extends Foo { }
    public static class BarImpl extends Bar { }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could do the following:

- Annotation the impl classes with `@XmlRootElement` instead of the abstract classes.
- Mark the abstract classes with `@XmlTransient` (see http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html)
- Use `@XmlElement(type=BarImpl.class)` on the `bar` property to specify the concrete type (see http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-interface-fronted-models.html).

**JAXBTest**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElements;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

import org.junit.Test;


public class JAXBTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws javax.xml.bind.JAXBException {
        String xml = 
            "<foo>" +
            "  <bar>" +
            "    <baz>qux</baz>" +
            "  </bar>" +
            "</foo>";

        javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext context = javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(
                FooImpl.class,
                BarImpl.class
        );

        javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

        unmarshaller.unmarshal(new java.io.StringReader(xml));
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public static abstract class Foo {
        @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name="bar",type=BarImpl.class),
            @XmlElement(name="bar",type=BarImpl2.class),
        })
        Bar bar;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public static abstract class Bar {
        @XmlElement(name="baz")
        String baz;
    }

    @XmlRootElement(name="foo")
    public static class FooImpl extends Foo { }

    @XmlRootElement(name="bar")
    public static class BarImpl extends Bar { }

    public static class BarImpl2 extends Bar { }
}
```

Comment: The one thing it's missing is that if I make BarImpl2, bar (in Foo) has already been marked as a BarImpl.

Comment: I have updated my answer to use `@XmlElements` to handle this use case.

Comment: It worked! The only annoyance now is that the implementer of BarImpl2 needs to change the annotations in Foo, but it's only an annoyance.

Comment: And if there's an abstract method without declaration of variable behind it? Say a bar getter but there is no bar variable declaration, can I still use @XmlElements... on the method itself to achieve the same behavior?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: Dear, I've tried your code but XmlTransient goes in error: "The XmlTransient is disallowed for this location". I've added public static abstract class DataGridData annotated with XmlTransient in my DataGrid class. Where's my fault?

Comment: @JoeTaras did you find a solution for your problem? I think I'm facing the same issue. I get "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 12 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions" on start if I use XmlTransient annotation.