# jaxb unable to create an instance of abstract class

Tags: java, web-services

```
@XmlSeeAlso({ Dog.class, Cat.class })
public abstract class Animal {}

@XmlRootElement(name="dog")
public class Dog extends Animal {}

@XmlRootElement(name="cat")
public class Cat extends Animal {}

@WebService(name = "WebServiceDemo", serviceName = "WebServiceDemo")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL,
            parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class WebServiceDemo {

@WebMethod
public String service(@WebParam(name = "animal") Animal animal) {
       System.out.println("animal service calling.....");
       return animal;
}
}
```

Now when i am calling this service method from client with Animal calss as a parameter that time i am getting error-

> Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of Animal
>    - with linked exception:
>   [java.lang.InstantiationException]
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:616)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:244)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:583)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:181)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.XsiTypeLoader.startElement(XsiTypeLoader.java:73)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:455)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:433)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:71)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:240)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:277)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:246)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:123)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:314)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:293)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:244)
>       at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.JAXBDeserializer.deserialize(JAXBDeserializer.java:71)

Comment: Well, you cannot instantiate an abstract class by definition...

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580028/jaxb-and-abstract-classes) helps ?

Answer (score 3):

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, that is the basic rule for them in Java. From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html):

> An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may
>   not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated,
>   but they can be subclassed.

Jaxb internally will try to unmarshall your xml to the java object. But if it is not able to create an object of Animal, how will it work. Hence it throws the exception. You need to provide a non-abstract class to JaxB to work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.                                            yes i know that, but @XmlSeeAlso({ Dog.class, Cat.class })
annotation i have used in the top of my abstract class. According to javadoc "Instructs JAXB to also bind other classes when binding this class. 
Java makes it impractical/impossible to list all sub-classes of a given class. This often gets in a way of JAXB users, as it JAXB cannot automatically list up the classes that need to be known to JAXBContext. 
"

Comment: @user2594003 Have you checked the link shared in comments by 'The New Idiot'

Comment: yes Juned that I know. but i am talking about @XmlSeeAlso annotation is not working the way it should work.